# How to get around Same Origin Policy when sending http request to an API in other server?

Tags: api, http, server, same-origin-policy

My server is A. There is another server B, which has an API called C. When I looked at a page residing on server B, I saw that it sends an AJAX POST request to the API C through Same Origin Policy.

How can I get around this policy when I send a HTTP request from my server A to the API C, which is in another server B?

Comment: You can't........ it's there for security reasons. Well, unless you are able to whitelist your domain on the server you're hitting but I'm guessing that it's a 3rd party service so probably not!

Comment: @AdamJeffers I actually read some articles about this. They mentioned something like JSONP or using proxy, etc. Do they really help in my case?

Comment: If your calling an API directly through it's exposed end points, you shouldn't be having issues with CORS?

Comment: @AdamJeffers, the point is that I don't have any contact with server B.

Answer (score 0):

If the API C accepts `form-urlencoded` format you can create a form in your app in A and invoke `Submit` to the C URL in B.

Or, you can proxy the call through your A server. Basically your client POST to your server A, and your server A POST to B. The Same Origin Policy applies on browsers only, nothing prevents your server from POSTing itself.

Otherwise you will need to enable CORS in C.

http://enable-cors.org/

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a specification that enables
>   truly open access across domain-boundaries. If you serve public
>   content, please consider using CORS to open it up for universal
>   JavaScript/browser access.